# Fixing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.braintree.impl.BraintreeNativeImpl

Tags: java, codenameone

After importing the CN1Lib for Braintree and setting up my own Braintree server, I was ready to implement the client side of the Braintree API. I looked at Codenameone's GitHub for Braintree and followed the directions to use their tutorial code. When I inserted this chunk of code under an Actionlistener method of a button, I ran my app and received the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.braintree.impl.BraintreeNativeImpl

I looked at the console to trace the error and found it on the line with `jsProxy.set("onSuccessNonce", new JSFunction()`(This line is also enclosed with ** in the code below)

```
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)


package com.codename1.braintree;

import com.codename1.braintree.impl.BraintreeNative;
import com.codename1.braintree.impl.BraintreePaymentCallback;
import com.codename1.javascript.JSFunction;
import com.codename1.javascript.JSObject;
import com.codename1.javascript.JavascriptContext;
import com.codename1.system.NativeLookup;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

public class Purchase {
    static boolean flag;

    public Purchase() {
    }

    public static void startOrder(Purchase.Callback callback) {
        BraintreePaymentCallback.cb = callback;
        String token = callback.fetchToken();
        BraintreeNative bn = (BraintreeNative)NativeLookup.create(BraintreeNative.class);
        if (bn != null && bn.isSupported()) {
            bn.showChargeUI(token);
        } else {
            Form buy = new Form(new BorderLayout());
            Form previous = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
            buy.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToLeftBar("", '\ue5c9', (e) -> {
                previous.showBack();
            });
            BrowserComponent cmp = new BrowserComponent();
            buy.add("Center", cmp);
            cmp.addWebEventListener("onLoad", (e) -> {
                JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(cmp);
                JSObject jsProxy = (JSObject)ctx.get("{}");
                **jsProxy.set("onSuccessNonce", new JSFunction() {**
                    public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                        BraintreePaymentCallback.onPurchaseSuccess((String)args[0]);
                    }
                });
                jsProxy.set("onErrorCall", new JSFunction() {
                    public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                        BraintreePaymentCallback.onPurchaseFail((String)args[0]);
                    }
                });
                jsProxy.set("onCancelCall", new JSFunction() {
                    public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                        previous.showBack();
                    }
                });
            });
            cmp.setPage("<html><head>    <style type=\"text/css\">\n        html, body {\n            height: 100%;\n            padding: 0;\n            margin: 0;     \n        }\n        \n        /* Dummy CSS to fix bug in JavaFX webview that caused gibberish display */\n        .gm-style-mtc > div, .gm-style > div, .gm-style-cc > div, .gm-style {font-family:sans-serif !important;}\n    </style></head><body>\n<form id=\"checkout-form\" action=\"/transaction-endpoint\" method=\"post\">\n  <div id=\"error-message\"></div>\n\n  <label for=\"card-number\">Card Number</label>\n  <div class=\"hosted-field\" id=\"card-number\"></div>\n\n  <label for=\"cvv\">CVV</label>\n  <div class=\"hosted-field\" id=\"cvv\"></div>\n\n  <label for=\"expiration-date\">Expiration Date</label>\n  <div class=\"hosted-field\" id=\"expiration-date\"></div>\n\n  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"payment_method_nonce\">\n  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Pay\" disabled>\n</form>\n\n<!-- Load the Client component. -->\n<script src=\"https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.1/js/client.min.js\"></script>\n\n<!-- Load the Hosted Fields component. -->\n<script src=\"https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.1/js/hosted-fields.min.js\"></script>\n\n<script>\nvar authorization = \"" + token + "\";\nvar submit = document.querySelector('input[type=\"submit\"]');\n\nbraintree.client.create({\n  authorization: authorization\n}, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {\n  if (clientErr) {\n    // Handle error in client creation\n    onErrorCall(clientErr.toString());    return;\n  }\n\n  braintree.hostedFields.create({\n    client: clientInstance,\n    styles: {\n      'input': {\n        'font-size': '14pt'\n      },\n      'input.invalid': {\n        'color': 'red'\n      },\n      'input.valid': {\n        'color': 'green'\n      }\n    },\n    fields: {\n      number: {\n        selector: '#card-number',\n        placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'\n      },\n      cvv: {\n        selector: '#cvv',\n        placeholder: '123'\n      },\n      expirationDate: {\n        selector: '#expiration-date',\n        placeholder: '10/2019'\n      }\n    }\n  }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {\n    if (hostedFieldsErr) {\n      // Handle error in Hosted Fields creation\n      return;\n    }\n\n    submit.removeAttribute('disabled');\n  });\n});\nvar form = document.querySelector('#checkout-form');\nvar submit = document.querySelector('input[type=\"submit\"]');\n\nbraintree.client.create({\n  // Replace this with your own authorization.\n  authorization: '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'\n}, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {\n  if (clientErr) {\n    // Handle error in client creation\n    return;\n  }\n\n  braintree.hostedFields.create({\n    client: clientInstance,\n    styles: {\n      'input': {\n        'font-size': '14pt'\n      },\n      'input.invalid': {\n        'color': 'red'\n      },\n      'input.valid': {\n        'color': 'green'\n      }\n    },\n    fields: {\n      number: {\n        selector: '#card-number',\n        placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'\n      },\n      cvv: {\n        selector: '#cvv',\n        placeholder: '123'\n      },\n      expirationDate: {\n        selector: '#expiration-date',\n        placeholder: '10/2019'\n      }\n    }\n  }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {\n    if (hostedFieldsErr) {\n      // Handle error in Hosted Fields creation\n      return;\n    }\n\n    submit.removeAttribute('disabled');\n\n    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {\n      event.preventDefault();\n\n      hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {\n        if (tokenizeErr) {\n          // Handle error in Hosted Fields tokenization\n          return;\n        }\n\n        onSuccessNonce(payload.nonce);\n      });\n    }, false);\n  });\n});\n</script></body></html>", (String)null);
            buy.show();
        }

        if (flag) {
            BraintreePaymentCallback.onPurchaseCancel();
            BraintreePaymentCallback.onPurchaseFail((String)null);
            BraintreePaymentCallback.onPurchaseSuccess((String)null);
        }

    }

    public interface Callback {
        String fetchToken();

        void onPurchaseSuccess(String var1);

        void onPurchaseFail(String var1);

        void onPurchaseCancel();
    }
}
```

I have been spending sometime tryig to find a solution, but can't think of any. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all that and install the cn1lib using the extension manager in Codename One Settings.

- Right click the project
- Select Codename One -> Codename One Settings
- Extensions
- Type Braintree, click "Download"
- Right click the project
- Select Codename One -> Refresh cn1libs

The API should "just work".

If you want to work from the code you also need to copy all the native code within the project and look in the properties files to merge that into your project settings.

Alternatively you can just download the project and build the cn1lib using ant or NetBeans.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work for me. There is an error saying that "Library source does not match the bytecode for class Purchase"

Comment: Did you install from the extension manager and removed everything you previously did? What's the exact full error?

Comment: Is this in the simulator? Braintree doesn't work in the simulator as it expects native device functionality. You need to build the Android/iOS version of the app and the API should work as expected there.